# R - solve.QP.compact - Constraints are Inconsistent

Tags: r, quadprog

I'm trying to use solve.QP.compact to solve my quadratic problem under linear constraint. The function to minimize can be written as Beta Dmat Beta with Beta representing convex coefficients that should be positive (Beta > 0 and sum of the beta = 1). Dmat is the following:

```
Dmat <- matrix(c(109372234737,56220334574,73429834051,91873541870,71984996802,26694299175,59466668488,72903058589,34863587167,69990189651,56220334574,30472842846,41528929013,47926044961,39275554021,15336150547,31555630939,46390008065,18268007279,37264936709,73429834051,41528929013,66139008296,63287127518,56359545680,23281467618,42187566934,81859897202,23713602850,48982965873,91873541870,47926044961,63287127518,79910583327,62808190600,22813816846,50498032289,61764252981,29834680574,60303335045,71984996802,39275554021,56359545680,62808190600,61526678668,20293546244,40774759080,65131530787,23760877095,48696449409,26694299175,15336150547,23281467618,22813816846,20293546244,10710118459,16315334904,40553546897,8572539401,18248955543,59466668488,31555630939,42187566934,50498032289,40774759080,16315334904,34293058435,49072014208,19333916546,38891422022,72903058589,46390008065,81859897202,61764252981,65131530787,40553546897,49072014208,201860304636,23395941080,50359726205,34863587167,18268007279,23713602850,29834680574,23760877095,8572539401,19333916546,23395941080,11528523792,23285654687,69990189651,37264936709,48982965873,60303335045,48696449409,18248955543,38891422022,50359726205,23285654687,48461629142), nrow=10, ncol=10)
```

As solve.QP.compact, solves function -d^Tb + 1/2 b^TDb, I have

```
dvec <- rep(0,nrow(Dmat))`
```

and the constraints are defined by

```
Amat = matrix(data=0, nrow=nrow(Dmat), ncol=nrow(Dmat)+1)
Amat[1,] = 1
Amat[,1] = 1
```

and

```
Aind = matrix(data=0, nrow=nrow(Dmat)+1, ncol=nrow(Dmat)+1)
Aind[1,] = 1
Aind[1,1] = nrow(Dmat)
Aind[2,] = c(1, seq(1:nrow(Dmat)))
Aind[,1] = c(nrow(Dmat), seq(1:nrow(Dmat)))
```

The sum should equal to 1, and all other values should be positive, so I have bvec defined by

```
bvec = rep(0,nrow(Dmat)+1)
bvec[1] = 1
```

And I use solve.QP.compact

```
solve.QP.compact(Dmat = Dmat, dvec = dvec, Amat = Amat, Aind=Aind, bvec = bvec)
```

This results by the following error

```
constraints are inconsistent, no solution!
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try to set `bvec` a little above 0 where you set it to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something wrong with the huge numbers in `Dmat`.

Probably the elements of solution vector `b` as they are getting indistinguishable from `0` (see `.Machine$double.eps`) still resolve in `b^T D b` being too big and something inside `quadprog` makes constraints inconsistent.

Looks like this should help:

```
   Dmat <- Dmat / 10^6
```